# Decode array of encoded objects

Tags: hacking

I need some help from you.. my VPS was hacked.. I was trying to decode the files I found.. here the content of one php file, it's an array of encoded objects.

Can you help me? http://pastebin.com/eKX22EHx

```
<?php $array = array('blabla','blablabla','blablabla');$x = implode("", $array);$b64 = "\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5f\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65";$r13 = "\x73\x74\x72\x5f\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33";$gzc = "\x67\x7a\x75\x6e\x63\x6f\x6d\x70\x72\x65\x73\x73";eval($gzc($b64($r13($x))));?>
```

Comment: I'd like to know the content of the file.. rather than receive a how-to deal with compromised server. :)

Comment: Just replace `eval` with `print_r` and you are good to go.

Comment: @Dio then this is a programming question, and also not suited to SF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here there is the code decoded http://pastebin.com/d2w7AXrK
It seems similar to c99madshell http://www.akamai.com/dl/akamai/akamai-security-advisory-web-shells.pdf

Comment: These questions are of no real value, and off topic for serverfault (arguably on topic on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hacked+what+does+this+php+code+do)). Please don't answer blatantly off topic questions. -1.